# How to detect in VB6 if an event handler has been assigned?

Tags: events, vb6

If I have a class in VB6, with some events

```
Public Event SomethingHappened
```

and I later want to fire that event

```
RaiseEvent SomethingHappened
```

This works fine, in my form which is hosting the class

```
Public WithEvents TheObject as MyClass
...
Public Sub TheObject_SomethingHappened
...
```

BUT, is there any way to tell in the code which Raises the event, whether the event has been assigned a handler? 
Because I would like to do some default behaviour if not.

I see that in VB.NET there is a automatic "SomethingHappenedEvent" variable declared, but that doesn't seem to work in VB6.
I can't find any mention of this on Google, so I suspect it's not possible, but...

Comment: If I understood your requirement correctly, WithEvents should work for you. Please check MSDN for more details on WithEvents

Comment: The events work, I am using WithEvents on form hosting the class. THe problem is, how can this code tell if the form handles the event

Comment: Just declare a global boolean variable and modify it from inside the event. If you want to see if the code handled the event, just check your variable.

Comment: This feels like a bad design, to have the assignment or not of an event control whether some other behaviour occurs within the class. I'd make the "default behaviour or not" an explicit setting.

Comment: Events with ByRef Boolean "cancel default action" arguments are quite common in Microsoft's controls and classes.  So that should be an endorsement of the pattern as viable if nothing else.

Comment: @Bob77 Good comment. You could make it an answer - it is the best answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, Microsoft has often dealt with this in its controls and classes by passing a ByRef Boolean "cancel default action" argument to the event handler.

If the handler exist without setting Cancel = True before returning then a default action is taken by the component.

That could be taken as a viable pattern based on established use.  There may be alternatives but this seems pretty simple and clean to implement when you have events where you want to offer default actions.